# How do I use a computed range in formula?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

I currently use this formula:

`=sumif($E$2:$E$363,L3,$D$2:$D$363)`

I'd like to change it to instead of having the $D$363 hard coded, that it pick up the "363" part from another cell that I specify. Here was what I tried if that gives you any better indication of what I want to accomplish:

`=sumif($E$2:$E$363,L3,concatenate("$D$2:$D$",A1))`, where cell A1 has the value 363 in it.

This doesn't work though.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing that, here's an easy one:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ʺ$D$2:$D$ʺ & A1))
```